# Should I return only Json Objects from controller to view?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an intranet website using Active Directory. I just realized that I didn't think about the work load that the server or client would have to do (I never really had this kind of issue since this is my first big website, and my first internship). As I use ASP.NET MVC, I have sent objects through my models, and used these objects in controllers to pass them to my views. Sometimes I send back a list of objects that can be pretty big.

I read on SO that using Json objects significantly diminishes object size, so should I do that when my controller or model sends an object?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: JSON as opposed to what?

Comment: Well sometimes I return a view with a list of objects for example. Sorry maybe the question is a bit silly, but I know little about this.

Comment: Are you looking into creating a front-end that communicates with the back-end with JSON objects? Like Angular on the front and a Web API at the back? 'Cause that's a very different way of working opposite to MVC.

Comment: No, just wandering if sending big objects from my controller to my view would be too demanding for the server if you have many users sending requests at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC doesn't return "objects", it returns HTTP responses.

If you mean you want to consider populating a page using JSON data obtained from an API method (either from Web API or MVC itself), then yes, that will generally require fewer bytes to be transferred than, say, a full-blown HTML page containing the same information wrapped in HTML tags.

But that requires an entirely different approach to how you set up your application. Instead of populating an HTML page serverside and sending that to the client, you populate the HTML page clientside with data obtained through an AJAX call, for example through AngularJS.

In the end you may be able to shave off a few bits, but it'll require you to move your databinding code from your CSHtml view to HTML+JS. It's up to you to determine whether the minimal (you mention intranet, so bandwidth will be less of a problem) performance gain will be worth the increased development time.

Comment: Ok thanks much clearer now!